Home made hot tub, estimating 3500 pounds
Looking to add a hot tub. Max loaded weight 3500 pounds over 8'×3' on a deck.
Deck has joists 2x10s 12" to center across span. Stringer board 2x12", ledger 2x12", posts 6x6".
Tub will more than likely sit in between posts. All joists have metal hangers.
Deck is 12' from stringer to ledger.
Stringer is lag bolted into posts. Ledger is lag bolted into block.
Please advise, ty.

Floors/decks usually made for a load of 40 to 60 psf.  That tub(if my math is close to right) is about 145psf(8x3).  If it is 8x8, by 3 high, then 54psf, which still probably above load limits.

You will want/need an engineer to design extra supports, but I figure on two extra beams plus support posts.  So reducing the span to four feet, an engineer might say only need six foot span.

That's dead weight, I assume. Don't forget to account for live weight of humans. I would definitely get an engineer to spec this --  among other things, there is zero chanc your insurance will cover it if you don't. Remember too that pools and tubs are considered "attractive nuisances" by many insurers; they will probably insist on safety precautions. Make sure you have accounted for all the costs before starting.
